# Disable slide tab animation react native router flux android

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I want to disable the slide animation when I change my tab on react native router flux.

The main problem is I can see other pages when I slide from the first to last scene and It's buggy on some old phones.

I tried to set duration={0} but it's not working.

There is my Tabs tag and the first tab Scene :

```
                        <Tabs
                        key="tabbar"
                        style={{height: tabSize, borderTopWidth: 0.5, borderColor: "black"}}
                        showLabel={false}
                        showIcon={true}
                        tabBarPosition='bottom'
                        type={ActionConst.REPLACE}
                        swipeEnabled={false}

                        activeBackgroundColor="white"
                        inactiveBackgroundColor="white">


                        <Stack
                            key="profile_tab"
                            hideNavBar
                            type={ActionConst.REPLACE}
                            icon={ProfileTabContent}>
                            <Scene key="profilePage"
                                   component={ProfilePage}
                                   duration={0}
                                   type={ActionConst.REPLACE}
                                   initial
                                   hideNavBar={true}/>
                        </Stack>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the prop `animationEnabled={false}` to your Tabs component and that will remove the transition animation.